# How to check is Facebook video is live

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm developing an app that currently capture the comment on the facebook live with the graph API with the following link https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/server-sent-events/endpoints/live-comments/

Now i want make sure the user enter the correct live video ID before calling this, how can i actually check if user entered the correct live video ID?

Any API to check if the facebook live video ID is valid? I'm using the javascript SDK.